# making personal app for iPhone

Tags: iphone, provisioning-profile, renewal

I want to make an app and use it for myself only....

I don't want to submit it to apple..

I know about provision profile  ......
i also know that it expires after 3 months....

Is there any way so that i can continuously use the app without renewing that provision profile ?

If not then please tell me how to renew that provision profile without deleting my application's data.(I know how to renew the provision but i know about only one method that is delete and reinstall the app..... but delete my apps data..).

Help Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two possibilities:

1) Jailbreak you device(s).  Then you can deploy all day long without profiles.

2) Get a developer cert, put all of the app data into the application Documents directory, and turn on the app flag to let iTunes see it.  Then you can copy it out an back in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are signed up as an apple developer, you can just package the application for ad-hoc distribution, then you can just put it in iTunes or Xcode and sync it onto your phone/iPod. However I do not know what would happen if/when your subscription ran out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect you iPhone to your Mac
2. XCode -> Window -> Organizer
3. click on your device and manage your provisioning profiles (add, delete, ...)

Answer (score 0):

there are many third party sites where you can develop iphone app and submit them which in turn they will submit to the app store.

Answer (score -1):

...or just send to the store with a 10,000,000 $ price, then use a redeem code for yourself, then get it and take it off from the store (or leave it there... you may be lucky...)